# File is not uploading from android app to php server

Tags: java, php, android, post, file-upload

I have developed an android app for uploading file to PHP server. The app part is working fine and it shows upload success. But the file is not created in server. Please help me to upload file android app to server. Did there is any another solution?

The code is shown below.

Android Part

```
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
final String uploadFileName = "gt.png";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"+ uploadFileName);

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.3/work/filesharing/2.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                }
            }).start();
        }

    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='' + fileName + ''" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://192.168.1.3/work/filesharing/uploads/"
                                +uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("LOGTAG","Upload file to server Exception" + "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block



}
 }
```

PHP code

```
$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Android Permission added in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

When i click the upload button it shows File Upload Completed.

Comment: `it shows File Upload Completed.`. Yes. But that is what you display your self at 200. But the php script returns `echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";`. So what did it return? You are not even reading that response.

Comment: Check whether your PHP file is working properly, use Postman for that. If your PHP script is working fine then it's Android issue.